# Which allocator does std::vector's copy constructor use to allocate memory?

Tags: c++, allocator

I have a custom allocator template `MyAllocator<T>`. I am attempting to create a class template that essentially boils down to the following:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyClass<T> {
    std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>> &data;
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>> &data) : data(data) {}
    MyClass(std::vector<T> &data) : data(data) {}
}
```

My intention is to avoid copying `data` when its memory allocation was dictated by `MyAllocator<T>`. I know that this can be hairy in some contexts, but this class is a short-lived utility wrapper, and this is a performance-critical application.

The part that confuses me, however, is the member initializer list of the second constructor. After looking closely at the documentation, I can't seem to explain why this operation is type-safe. It is my understanding that `data(data)` will look for the constructor `std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>>::vector(std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>)` (or a pass-by-reference variant). This constructor doesn't seem to exist, yet I have not encountered any compile-time type errors.

At first I thought it was because the `data` member variable is a reference, but changing it to a value did not create any type errors. `MyAllocator` is not a subclass of `std::allocator`, so I don't see how an implicit cast could be responsible for this behavior either.

What am I missing? And if this is indeed legal code, does the second constructor create a new memory allocation with `MyAllocator` like I'm hoping it does?

Comment: Did you actually attempt to use that constructor?

Comment: You should get a compilation error at `data(data)`. `std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T>> &` won't bind to a `std::vector<T> &`. None of the `std::vector` constructors come into play here. Initializing a reference from a reference doesn't construct or convert any object. Probably the code shown isn't an accurate representation of your actual code. Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: `yet I have not encountered any compile-time type errors.` Please post a full [MCVE]. Your code, as presented, surely is a compile-time error - ending `}` is missing and `#include <vector>` may be missing. (And definition of `MyAllocator` is missing).

Comment: @T.C. I suppose this was the answer. For an inexplicable reason, I am able to compile this code as a static library, but type errors occur upon use in an executable.